# Dynamically build AJAX request based onChange event in form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

So I have several form elements which are currently acting as filters - I plan to use this as a basis for a search feature on my website.

I was thinking about linking a set of on change events to dyanmically build an AJAX query that selects fields from a set of tables but I'm not too sure how I can go about doing it.

On page load I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/uVhzZ/. The pseudo SQL for this setup would be: `SELECT * from ts_rooms WHERE capacity >= 50` (Any means no **WHERE** condition has been set)

However when the user starts to make changes, I would like this additions to be dynamically added to the SQL query - for instance if Lecture Style is set to Lab and capacity changes to 75 then pseudo SQL would change to `SELECT * from ts_rooms WHERE capacity >= 75 AND lectureStyle="Lab"`;

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you gotta prepare your AJAX request, it can be done by creating an array with all selects you wanna use (you can look on ther .val() and if it has any value you add this value to that array using the select id as array key) then converting it to JSON.

PHP will receive this JSON string and convert it to array. Then you can look thru this array, and for each element you go building your where statement.

Then it's just a matter of taking query resultset and build another array from it, converting to JSON and responding to JS.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your elements in a form, post it to your php search file. Created a sql query with the relevant constraints and return data in json and display it.